# Sharepoint data base management

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

Dose anyone know a tools for SharePoint content data base management (add/remove,attach ... the content database )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is the best "Tool" for this job.

Are there any other specific requirements you have?

Comment: thanks, i wonder if there is a solution or an codeplex project it could help , if not we will take the powershell way :)

Comment: what is it that you need help with that cannot be accommodated with PowerShell or Central Administration?